# A button which goes onto an Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, button, menu, screen

I have been trying to figure this thing out with no luck in eclipse. I have created 3 screens. One being the main menu which a button leading to another button which then leads to an Activity. I can get the button from the main menu to lead onto the button onto the second screen but i can't get the second button to lead onto the third screen.

Can anybody help me?

appproject

Comment: could u please post some of your code of your second screen?

Answer (score 0):

You should really post some code so we can help you...but it seems like you need to look at your `onClick()` method for the second button.

Providing you have three separate `Activities` for each of these three screens (I'll call them ActivityA, ActivityB, and ActivityC), you'll also probably need an XML layout for each. There are ways of doing it without an XML layout, but for now just stick with that.

The next thing is you want to make sure your Button is initialized properly. ActivityB should look like:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        Button b = new (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            protected void onClick() {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
            }
        });
    }
```

The first thing you should do is check to make sure your button functions in a way similar to how I've described here. If that doesn't change anything, make sure you are initializing your Button in accordance to how it is defined in the layout XML. You must use an id for a Button that is in the same XML layout as the one you set in `setContentView()`. If not, it will do nothing, no matter what you put in the `onClick()` method.

I hope that helps!!